# Bilateral ZTransform

Tags: integral-transforms

Is there support for [bilateral Z-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Bilateral_Z-transform) in *Mathematica*, or a third-party package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the nicest things about *Mathematica* is that one can often just implement the definitions as they are:

```
bilateralZTransform[c_, k_, z_, opts___] := Sum[c/z^k, {k, -∞, ∞}, opts]
```

Otherwise, one can exploit the relationship between `GeneratingFunction[]` and `ZTransform[]`:

```
bilateralZTransform[c_, k_, z_, opts___] :=
                    ZTransform[HeavisideTheta[k - 1] c, k, z, opts] +
                    GeneratingFunction[Function[k, c][-k], k, z, opts]
```