# Z-Transform Solution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to solve the z-transform of the following sequence using Mathematica:

```
x[n]=-a^n u[-n-1]
```

The known result is $X(z)=z/(z-a)$ with ROC: $|z|<|a|$.

The Mathematica is unable to solve this case using the command:

```
ZTransform[-a^n UnitStep[-n-1], n, z, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

Would you mind me telling what the problem is?

Comment: I believe you are looking for the Bilateral ZTransform.  See: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87548/bilateral-ztransform

Comment: That's right. Thank you for your help !!